# Unable to proxy_pass nginx to different ports on different end points

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I'm trying to reverse proxy on different ports when called on different endpoints... but for some reason, only the root endpoint '/' seems to work. and the other endpoint i.e location /mah/  doesn't seem to work. below is the default.conf

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name    expmple.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/;

}
location /mah/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
}
 #followed my ssl keys
}
```

The node servers which are listening on the respective ports serve a static webpage using express i.e

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const PORT =8000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "frontend", "build")));
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

There's no error but a blank screen is being displayed in the browser.
[note: when i try to switch ports: 8000 on / and 8001 on /mah/. everything is running fine on /. but /mah/ is not working.]  I have tried multiple things like rewrite, adding proxy_set_headers but nothing seems to work. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx proxy should be a map with the same path in your express route path.

Try pointing the endpoint of your express running on port 8000 to `/mah`. In your example, it should be like this.

```
app.use('/mah', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "frontend", "build")));
```

Why it's working on the `location /`? because the express app running on port 8001

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "frontend", "build")));
```

defaults to point to `/` route. This is the same with

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "frontend", "build")));
```